# CakePHP find list with related model conditions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, relational-database

I'm trying to get a list of IDs (a la `find('list')`), but can't figure out how to do it with related model conditions.

My associations are:
`Product hasAndBelongsToMany Category`
`Product belongsTo Manufacturer`

I want to find a list of product IDs that are in a list of category IDs and have a certain manufacturer seo_url. I've tried tons of contains with conditions, conditions referencing other models, even tried using find('all') to see if my conditions would work, but couldn't get anything.

I managed to get one with Product->query(), but it's not in the format of a list. I could cycle through the array and grab IDs or whatever, but it feels awfully un-Cakey. I want to make sure Cake still does all its security checks on my queries and whatever other automagic it does. Here's the query I got working:

```
$all_results = $return['Category']['all_results'] = $this->Product->query('
    SELECT `Product`.`id`
        FROM `categories_products` as `CategoriesProduct`
        JOIN `products` as `Product` ON (`CategoriesProduct`.`product_id` = `Product`.`id`)
        JOIN `manufacturers` as `Manufacturer` ON (`Product`.`manufacturer_id` = `Manufacturer`.`id` AND `Manufacturer`.`seo_url` = \''.$manufacturer.'\')
        WHERE `CategoriesProduct`.`category_id` IN ('.implode(',', $search_categories).')
');
```

this returns

```
[all_results] => Array
    (
         [0] => Array
            (
                [Product] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 101787
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Product] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 100781
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Product] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 101887
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [Product] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 101888
                    )

            )

    )
```

Note: `$search_categories` is the list of category ID's (ie: `array(12,42,24,5)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your wanted result is, that Cake won't give you back a stripped result array if you use conditions on your related models.

This happens because Cake will only use these conditions on your related model and give you back the results with conditions being true on your related models.

If you want get back products with only specific Category you need to query through the Category-Model as this gives you the possibility to use the conditions on your Products. This could look something like this:

```
$this->Category->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Category.id' => 2));
```

This will give you back only the wanted Category and its associated Products.
However, this is not very satisfying if you want a list, because you would have to manually do the conversion.

I would rather take a look at the [Linkable Plugin](https://github.com/Terr/Linkable) which should give you exactly your wanted functionality as it extends Cake in using joins as you did in your query. This makes it possible on getting results with conditions on your related models.

Comment: I decided to just manually convert the find array to a list. Only took 3 lines of code, so it's not too bad. Linkable plugin looks interesting, but I don't have much experience with plugins. Thanks for the help

Comment: Rob, could you add the "3 lines of code" to your question so I can also convert my code in the same way?

Comment: $ids = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($all_results as $result) {
    $ids[$i] = $result['id'];
    $i++;
}
Maybe a little bit late, but this code worked:)

Comment: As @Victor suggested, you can do it with find(all) and then use Set::Combine().

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP can be odd about `conditions` for related models. Especially with HABTM relationships. Even when `recursive` is set to the highest value (i.e. 2). Check out the docs for more detail about [HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM).

Try the following. Although from the above, I don't think it will work:

```
$conditions = array('Category.id' => $category_ids, 'Manufacturer.seo_url' => $manufacturer);
$this->Product('list', array('recursive' => 1, 'conditions' => $conditions));
```

Also, avoid `query()` whenever possible. The whole point of MVC is to insulate *data* from *display* from *logic*. Using things like `query()` just breaks that.

Comment: Yep, that's why I'm trying to figure out how to convert that query to Cake. I tried with recursive, tried using contain => array(Manufacturer => array(conditions => array())) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do a normal condition and change into list format after.

```
$this->loadModel('AlertStatuses');  
$lists = $this->AlertStatuses->find('all', [ 
'conditions'=>['AlertStatuses.id > 2']]);
$alert_statuses  = array();
foreach($lists as $list) {
  $alert_statuses[$list->id] = $list->name;
}
$this->set('alert_statuses', $alert_statuses);
```