# CakePHP 2.2.4: Converting this find('all') to a Select List

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm working on a Forum controller and I'm having an issue generating the drop down select of forum categories.

```
Forum hasmany ForumCategory (forum_id)
ForumCategory hasmany ForumPost (category_id)
ForumCategory hasmany ForumSubcat (parent_id)
ForumCategory belongs to Forum (forum_id)
ForumPost belongs to ForumCategory (category_id)
ForumSubcat belongs to ForumCategory (parent_id)
Forum belongs to Page (page_id)
```

When a user goes to add a new thread for the forum (model is called ForumPost), they must select a category_id (ForumCategory). If user goes to http://www.domain.com/forum/add/5, the category_id should be preselected as 5 with the title of the category displayed. If user goes to http://www.domain.com/forum/add, the category_id should be unselected and the dropdown should start with the default option “Select a Category”.

The code for that is

```
if($category_id){
    echo $this->Form->input('category_id', array('value' => $category_id, 'empty' => 'Select a Category'));
}
else{
    echo $this->Form->input('category_id', array('empty' => 'Select a Category'));
}
```

$category_id is passed from route to controller to view and the above code is currently working.

**I want my select list to be hierarchal, displaying all the forums with the page_id = $page_id  (so the condition has to be on the Forum model). Below that, all the categories belonging to the above forum. And finally below that, all the sub categories belonging to the parent category. Here is an example:**

```
Select a Category // default option
Help // Forum
--- Announcements // Category
--- Feedback & Suggestions // Category
--- Questions & Support // Category
General Discussion // Forum
--- Games & Polls // Category
--- Introductions // Category
--- Chit Chat // Category
Off Topic // Forum
--- Movies // Category
--- TV // Category
--- Music // Category
-------- Pop // Sub Category
-------- Rock // Sub Category
-------- R&B // Sub Category
--- Games // Category
```

I need it so that if a user selects a forum option say “Off Topic”, that the id for the select is null and validation will tell them to choose a category until their pick is  either a category or sub category option.

I have tried a few methods but I’m really missing the ball on this one.

This gives me a valid list of categories grouped by their corresponding forum and the condition of `Forum.page_id = $page_id` works but the sub categories do not fall under their parent.

```
$this->ForumCategory->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('ForumCategory.id', 'ForumCategory.title', 'Forum.title'),
    'conditions' => array('Forum.page_id' => $page_id),
    'recursive' => 0
));
```

This gives me the array I want but not in a select-compatible list. **Is there a way I can covert it nicely or should I not use the form helper for this field?**

```
 $this->Forum->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('Forum.title'),
    'conditions' => array('Forum.page_id' => $page_id),
    'contain' => array(
        'ForumCategory' => array(
            'ForumSubcat'
        )
    )
));
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023349/cakephp-find-list-with-related-model-conditions) on StackOverflow was the biggest help but the original poster did not update the question to include their conversion of a find('all') into a list.

Comment: I suggest breaking this down into more manageable/smaller questions.  Ie.  I can't get a value to pass to the view.  And - how to I set a value to the options of a select box...etc etc.

Comment: part of my problem is solved, I had to change forum_category_id to category_id so now the list for the first query I tried was displayed properly. Now I have one issue which is that the sub categories don't fall under their parent for the find('list') and for the other option of find('all') it is not a valid select list.